# How can I prevent automatic body subscripting when using the tufte-book class?

Tags: subscripts, tufte

I'm using Overleaf with the tufte-book class to create lecture notes for an aviation course.

When departing from Dallas-Fort Worth International Airport, one of the possible departure procedures is the `HRPER3` procedure, properly displayed just as you see it here.  In the body text of the book, however, the numerals become subscripted.  Also notice that this happens whether or not I use \textsc{} but it does not happen in the sidenotes. This seems to be because I have `sfsidenotes` activated in the preamble.  However, I don't really want my body text in sans serif.

**Is there a way to prevent this automatic subscripting in the body text of a tufte-book?**

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,oneside,justified,marginals=raggedright]{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Enroute}
\section{Preferred and Coded Departure Routes}
\subsection{Coded Departure Routes}

CDRs are relatively new\sidenote{They've only been around since 2007} and they're not perfect yet.  Here's an example.  Suppose you plan to depart from KDFW on your way to KMKE, and suppose that the preferred routing uses the \textsc{HRPER3} departure,\sidenote{I have no idea if HRPER3 really is the preferred route} but there's storms directly along your route.  As you're doing your preflight planning, you realize those storms might interfere with your proposed departure, so you review the coded departure routes as well.  You discover that the DFWMKE1E CDR would provide adequate separation from all severe weather and file that CDR as an alternate in your flight plan.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think what's happening here is that oldstyle numerals are being used.  they're not subscripted, only a different design with a rather small "1" and a "3" that hangs below the baseline.  i don't know how to change to lining numerals, since i don't use this class, but i believe it can be done.  check the documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I haven't read the documentation as I don't use this class either, but the code suggests that it is all-or-nothing: you can switch off the font configuration, but then you get the default CM/OT1 setup. However, you may well be right and I've not looked hard enough. (I'm just explaining why my answer is rather more circuitous than your comment suggests may be necessary.)

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question as a duplicate, as I just discovered (after all this time) that a better answer exists at the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not be subscripted. Rather, `tufte` tells the font package it loads to use old style or hanging figures, which are considered more suitable for use in text according to traditional typographical guidelines.

However, they do not work well with things like acronyms. I'm not sure that the font package `tufte` loads allows you to easily switch between old style and lining figures, which would be ideal. However, you can simply use lining figures throughout.

```
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,oneside,justified,marginals=raggedright]{tufte-book}
\makeatletter
\pazo@osffalse
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Enroute}
\section{Preferred and Coded Departure Routes}
\subsection{Coded Departure Routes}

CDRs are relatively new\sidenote{They've only been around since 2007} and they're not perfect yet.  Here's an example.  Suppose you plan to depart from KDFW on your way to KMKE, and suppose that the preferred routing uses the \textsc{HRPER3} departure,\sidenote{I have no idea if HRPER3 really is the preferred route} but there's storms directly along your route.  As you're doing your preflight planning, you realize those storms might interfere with your proposed departure, so you review the coded departure routes as well.  You discover that the DFWMKE1E CDR would provide adequate separation from all severe weather and file that CDR as an alternate in your flight plan.

\end{document}
```

[image: lining figures]

Alternatively, you can give the `nofonts` option to the class to prevent its font configuration.

```
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,oneside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nofonts]{tufte-book}
```

This will result in the default LaTeX fonts being used.

If you want `tufte`'s fonts except for the hanging figures, you can add

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

to your preamble to emulate the configuration.

This assumes that you are using (pdf)TeX to compile and not LuaTeX or XeTeX, for example.